# Averaging values between files, but keeping non-matching values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two files:

File 1:

```
key.1   10    6 
key.2    5    6
key.3.   5    8
key.4.   5    10
key.5    4    12
```

File 2:

```
key.1   10    6 
key.2    6    6
key.4    5    10
key.5    2    8
```

I have a rather complicated issue. I want to average between the two files for each loc. ID. But if an ID is unique to either of the files, I simply want to keep that value in the output file. So the output file would look like this:

```
key.1   10    6 
key.2   5.5   6
key.3.   5    8
key.4.   5    10
key.5    3    10
```

This is an example. In reality I have 100s of columns that I would like to average.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following solution uses Pandas, and assumes that your data is stored in plain text files 'file1.txt' and 'file2.txt'. Let me know if this assumption is incorrect - it is likely a minimal edit to alter for different file types. If I have misunderstood your meaning of the word 'file' and your data is already in DataFrames, you can ignore the first step.

First read in the data to DataFrames:

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.read_table('file1.txt', sep=r'\s+', header=None)
df2 = pd.read_table('file2.txt', sep=r'\s+', header=None)
```

Giving us:

```
In [9]: df1
Out[9]: 
       0   1   2
0  key.1  10   6
1  key.2   5   6
2  key.3   5   8
3  key.4   5  10
4  key.5   4  12

In [10]: df2
Out[10]: 
       0   1   2
0  key.1  10   6
1  key.2   6   6
2  key.4   5  10
3  key.5   2   8
```

Then join these datasets on column 0:

```
combined = pd.merge(df1, df2, 'outer', on=0)
```

Giving:

```
       0  1_x  2_x   1_y   2_y
0  key.1   10    6  10.0   6.0
1  key.2    5    6   6.0   6.0
2  key.3    5    8   NaN   NaN
3  key.4    5   10   5.0  10.0
4  key.5    4   12   2.0   8.0
```

Which is a bit of a mess, but we can select only the columns we want after doing the calculations:

```
combined[1] = combined[['1_x', '1_y']].mean(axis=1)
combined[2] = combined[['2_x', '2_y']].mean(axis=1)
```

Selecting only useful columns:

```
results = combined[[0, 1, 2]]
```

Which gives us:

```
       0     1     2
0  key.1  10.0   6.0
1  key.2   5.5   6.0
2  key.3   5.0   8.0
3  key.4   5.0  10.0
4  key.5   3.0  10.0
```

Which is what you were looking for I believe.

You didn't state which file format you wanted the output to be, but the following will give you a tab-separated text file. Let me know if something different is preferred and I can edit.

```
results.to_csv('output.txt', sep='\t', header=None, index=False)
```

I should add that it would be better to give your columns relevant labels rather than using numbers as I have in this example - I just used the default integer values here since I don't know anything about your dataset.

Comment: This is a nice pandas solution and I upvote. But user has 100s of columns - so would be useful to show how this can be adapted.

Comment: @jpp Thanks, I somehow missed the 100s of columns part. I've just tested your answer with some extra columns and it works well, so I think it is the best solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `itertools.groupby`:

```
import itertools
import re
file_1 = [[re.sub('\.$', '', a), *list(map(int, filter(None, b)))] for a, *b in [re.split('\s+', i.strip('\n')) for i in open('filename.txt')]]
file_2 = [[re.sub('\.$', '', a), *list(map(int, filter(None, b)))] for a, *b in [re.split('\s+', i.strip('\n')) for i in open('filename1.txt')]]
special_keys ={a for a, *_ in [re.split('\s+', i.strip('\n')) for i in open('filename.txt')]+[re.split('\s+', i.strip('\n')) for i in open('filename2.txt')] if a.endswith('.')}
new_results = [[a, [c for _, *c in b]] for a, b in itertools.groupby(sorted(file_1+file_2, key=lambda x:x[0])[1:], key=lambda x:x[0])]
last_results = [(" "*4).join(["{}"]*3).format(a+'.' if a+'.' in special_keys else a, *[sum(i)/float(len(i)) for i in zip(*b)]) for a, b in new_results]
```

Output:

```
['key.1    10.0    6.0', 'key.2    5.5    6.0', 'key.3.    5.0    8.0', 'key.4.    5.0    10.0', 'key.5    3.0    10.0']
```

Answer (score 1):

This is one solution via `pandas`. The idea is to define indices for each dataframe and use `^` [equivalent to `symmetric_difference` in `set` terminology] to find your unique indices.

Treat each case separately via 2 `pd.concat` calls, perform a `groupby.mean`, and append your isolated indices at the end.

```
# read files into dataframes
df1 = pd.read_csv('file1.csv')
df2 = pd.read_csv('file2.csv')

# set first column as index
df1 = df1.set_index(0)
df2 = df2.set_index(0)

# calculate symmetric difference of indices
x = df1.index ^ df2.index
# Index(['key.3'], dtype='object', name=0)

# aggregate common and unique indices
df_common = pd.concat((df1[~df1.index.isin(x)], df2[~df2.index.isin(x)]))
df_unique = pd.concat((df1[df1.index.isin(x)], df2[df2.index.isin(x)]))

# calculate mean on common indices; append unique indices
mean = df_common.groupby(df_common.index)\
                .mean()\
                .append(df_unique)\
                .sort_index()\
                .reset_index()

# output to csv
mean.to_csv('out.csv', index=False)
```

**Result**

```
       0     1     2
0  key.1  10.0   6.0
1  key.2   5.5   6.0
2  key.3   5.0   8.0
3  key.4   5.0  10.0
4  key.5   3.0  10.0
```

Answer (score -2):

One possible solution is to read the two files into dictionaries (key being the key variable, and the value being a list with the two elements after). You can then get the keys of each dictionary, see which keys are duplicated (and if so, average the results), and which keys are unique (and if so, just output the key). This might not be the most efficient, but if you only have hundreds of columns that should be the simplest way to do it.

Look up set intersection and set difference, as they will help you find the common items and unique items.

Comment: Here's a good python set tutorial: https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/set

Comment: pls implement what you're saying